# Existence of the group of multipicative represents of elements of $\mathbb{F}_p^\ast$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

let $U=\mathbb{Z}_p^\ast$ the group of $p$-adic units. And $V=\{x\in U\mid x^{p-1} = 1\}$ the group of multiplicative representations of the elements of $\mathbb{F}_p^\ast$.

It is stated, that the existence of this set follows when you apply the following lemma:

> Every simple zero of the reduction modulo $p$ of a polynomial $f$ lifts to a zero of $f$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

To the function $f(x)=x^{q-1}-1$.

Going after the lemma we have to solve $x^{q-1}-1\equiv 0\mod p$. Therefore $x^{q-1}\equiv 1\mod p$. Obviously $x=1$ is a solution.
We have to check, that $f'(1)\not\equiv 0\mod p$.

$$f'(x)=(q-1)x^{q-2} \text{ and } f'(1)=q-1. \quad q-1\not\equiv 0\bmod p\Longleftrightarrow p\nmid q-1$$

But I do not see why this has to hold.
For the existence of $V$ we have to show, that $V\neq\emptyset$, am I right?

How do I have to apply the lemma here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Hensel lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Derivation) has a detailed proof, apply it to $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p^n \implies (a+tp^n)^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p^{n+1}$ has a solution for $t$. Do you see how it gives a $p$-adic number such that $\alpha^{p-1} = 1$ ?

Comment: When I observe the function $f(t)=(a+tp^n)^{p-1}-1$ it has a solution x with $f(x)=(a+xp^n)^{p-1}-1\equiv 0\mod p$, since it is also congruent $0\mod p^{n+1}$. Now I have to check, if $x$ is also a zero of $f'(t)=(p-1)p^n(a+tp^n)^{p-2}$. Is that correct?

Comment: The above is wrong... when $y\equiv 0\mod p^{n+1}$ we do not get $y\equiv 0\mod p$ ... that was dumb.

Comment: $f(t) = (a+tp^n)^{p-1}-1 = f(0)+ t p^n f'(0)+ p^{2n}t^2 g(t)$ where $f(0) = a^{p-1}-1, f'(0) = (p-1) a^{p-2}$. Thus how do we choose $b$ such that $f(b) \equiv 0 \bmod p^{n+1}$ ?

Comment: When we choose $t=p$, we get $f(p)=f(0)+p^{n+1}f'(0)+p^{2(n+1)}g(p)\equiv f(0)\mod p^{n+1}$ but not $0$.

Comment: No. Try with $a = 3, p = 2, n= 1$ ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: No, to choosing t=p, or that $a^{p-1}-1\not\equiv 0\mod p^{n+1}$. I thought that we maybe can use Fermat's little theorem here. Which stats that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ when $p\nmid a$, so $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p^{n+1}$

Comment: Come on, the goal is to find $A = a+tp^n$ such that $A^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p^{n+1}$. Fermat little theorem works only for $n=0$ ie. the base case.

Comment: If I try a=3, p=2, n=1, I get $f(t)=(3+2t)-1=2+2t=2(t+1)$ Now I want to give $t$ such that $2t+2\equiv 0 \mod 4$. t=1 does the trick. So do we search $t=p-1$ in general?

Comment: No...... $f(0) \equiv 0 \bmod p^n$ thus $f(0) \equiv c p^n \bmod p^{n+1}$ thus $f(t) \equiv ...$

Comment: $f(t)=f(0)+tp^nf'(0)+p^{2n}t^2g(t)\equiv cp^n+tp^nf'(0)+p^{2n}t^2g(t)\mod p^{n+1}$. When we factor out $p^n$ we have to show, that $c+tf'(0)+p^nt^2g(t)\equiv 0\mod p\Leftrightarrow c+tf'(0)\equiv 0\mod p$. Hence $c+t(p-1)a^{p-2}\equiv 0\mod p$. I do not find such a $t$. :(

Comment: You don't know how to solve $c + td \equiv 0 \bmod p$ ? Are you kidding ?

Comment: Clearly your level is too low, if you want to study such topics, download many more books and pdf instead of asking on MSE where nobody will write a detailed proof just for you.

Comment: Well, then $t\equiv -d\cdot c^{-1}\mod p$ and we have $c^{-1}$ since $p\nmid c$.

Comment: If you have the aspiration to lead the OP to the solution wihout giving a complete answer, then you should also bring the patience for it. Otherwise do us both a favor and stay away from my questions, when you rather insult instead of giving a detailed proof just for me.

Comment: Your level is too low because you need detailed proofs, so download many pdf instead of asking on MSE.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: https://www.google.fr/search?q=hensel+lemma+proof https://www.google.fr/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+hensel+lemma+proof

Comment: I do not have to expect a further answer to my comment above? Anyways thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you want more ? Hensel lemma says it reduces to solving $c+tf'(0) \equiv 0 \bmod p$. Here $f'(0)^{-1}$ has a simple expression.

Comment: So we take $t\equiv -cf'(0)^{-1}\mod p$ and conclude that $V$ is not empty. And therefore the set exists?

Comment: What to say ? What you wrote about $V $ and $\emptyset$ is a nonsense. Do you see how to construct $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_p, \alpha^{p-1} = 1$ from Hensel lemma ?

Comment: No, I do not see how to construct this... :(

Comment: See my comment to your previous question where I explain $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a ring of sequences.

Comment: So we take $\alpha=(\dotso, \alpha_m,\dotso, \alpha_0)$ with $\alpha_n\in\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$. Since we multiply coordinate by coordinate it has to be $\alpha_0^{p-1}=1$ and every other coordinate has to be 1 aswell. So it has to be $\alpha_0=1$. Using hensels lemma we lift $\alpha_0$ to $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_1$ to $\alpha_2$ and so on.

Comment: Yes. In other words As an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p/p^n\mathbb{Z}_p \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} $ our $ \alpha $ is our solution $x^{p-1}\equiv 1 \bmod p^n$ lifted from  $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \bmod p$. And for the $|.|_p$ metric/absolute value $\alpha= \lim_{m \to \infty} \alpha_m$

Comment: And what can we conclude from this? Is this still related to finding a value of t such that $f(t)\equiv 0\mod p^{n+1}$

Comment: I do not know why you think this is helping in any way. It is just frustrating to receive a respond like that.

Comment: Because your question makes no sense given all what we said. Make things precise mathematically and you'll be able to find where you are stuck exactly.

Comment: And I do not see how it makes sense to ask how to construct $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ from $\alpha^{p-1}=1$ with Hensel's Lemma, when we tried to find a $t$ such that $f(t)\equiv 0\mod p^{n+1}$ which is not answered yet.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now I understand what we were trying to do the whole time much better. Which was the problem in the first place, I guess.

Comment: Your comment "so we take $\alpha= \ldots$" says it, and the comments above show the lifts/Hensel lemma reduce at each step to $c+td \equiv 0 \bmod p$ with $d = f'(0)$ inversible.  Thus $\{ \alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_p, \alpha^{p-1} = 1\}$ are one-to-one with $\{ a \in \mathbf{F}_p, a^{p-1} = 1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to using Hensel's lemma. 
A roadmap to proving that $|V|=p-1$. You fill in the remaining details.

1. Fix an integer $a$ in the range $1,2,\ldots,p-1$.
2. Define the sequence $x_n=a^{p^n}$, $n=1,2,3,\ldots$.
3. Show that whenever $n<m$ we have the congruence
   $$x_m\equiv x_n\pmod{p^n}.$$
4. Conclude that $|x_m-x_n|_p\le 1/p^n$ whenever $n<m$. Therefore the sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy.
5. By completeness of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ we can conclude that the limit
   $$\zeta_a=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$$ exists as an element of $\Bbb{Q}_p$.
6. Show that $x_{n+1}=x_n^p$. Conclude that $\zeta_a^p=\zeta_a$.
7. Show that $\zeta_a\equiv a\pmod p$.
8. Show that $\zeta_a\neq0$ for all $a$.
9. Show that $\zeta_a^{p-1}=1$ for all $a$.
10. Show that $\zeta_a\neq\zeta_b$ whenever $a,b$ are distinct integers in the range $0<a,b<p$. Conclude that you have found $p-1$ distinct zeros of $f(x)=x^{p-1}-1$ in $\Bbb{Q}p$.

---

Using the Lemma:

- Show that $a\in\Bbb{F}_p^*$ is a zero of $f(x)=x^{p-1}-1$.
- Show that $f'(a)\neq0.$
- The Lemma says that $f(x)$ has a zero $\zeta_a\in\Bbb{Z}_p$ such that $\zeta_a\equiv a\pmod{p\Bbb{Z}_p}.$
- See item 10 from the first solution.

Comment: I am struggeling with the step 3. How can I see that $x_m\equiv x_n\mod p^n$ for $m>n$. I tried $x_m=a^{p^m}=a^{p^{n+k}}=(a^{p^n})^{p^k}$

Comment: @Cornman Show that $p^m-p^n$ is a multiple of $p^n(p-1)=\phi(p^{n+1})$. And recall that $a^{\phi(p^{n+1})}\equiv1\pmod{p^{n+1}}.$

Comment: Unfortunatly I have not seen the proof for this statement. Is there an other method which does not involve Euler's $\phi$-function?

Comment: @Cornman That result is [rather elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)). Much simpler than anything about $p$-adics.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didnt know that it boils down to Lagrang's theorem. Anyways: It is $p^m-p^n=p^n(p^k-1)=p^n(p-1)(p^{k-1}+p^{k-2}+\dotso +1)$. Therefore a multiple of $p^n(p-1)$